# Colour change for an object with multiple materials?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, texturing, color

The object is going to roll while being rainbow colored, stop and then change to red all over, the problem is that all the different objects have different materials used to make them up, so when i assign a key frame for a color, it doesn't stay rainbow colored while rolling and is instead just red. i'm using key frames made from base materials in the editor.
[image]

Comment: i would change the color via nodes in the shader editor - so you just have one material for all. Here you can also change the color dependent on your timeframe.

Comment: This worked for some of the strands, but the issue is that there are a lot of materials, in the hundreds so changing them may be too time consuming. would starting again with seperated objects being better?

Comment: I’d doesn’t look like hundreds of colors…I see just 6….

Comment: I coloured them and copied them, so may need to backtrack and add the colours after the mesh lol

Comment: I figured it out by backtracking, thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome